# JavaScript alert says 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, html

Good evening, folks.

I've been studying the foundations of JS and i got stuck with the following code, where the HTML page is supposed to receive a value in metters:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
</head>
<html>
<title>Exercícios js</title>
    <body>
        <p>Insira os dados: </p> <input type="text" name="dados" id="dados" placeholder="Digite a altura em metros">
        <button type="button" id="btn-click" onclick="conversor()">Converter !</button>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/motor.js">
            document.getElementById("btn-click").addEventListener("click");            

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And with a function called `conversor()` within a separate .js, it's supposed to return the value in feet:

```
var pes = (document.getElementById("dados")) * 0.305;

function conversor(){


    alert('A altura em metros é: ' + (pes)). parseFloat(value);
}
```

The page alert says 'undefined'. My clue is that I'm trying to retrieve text inputs and then multiply it to a floating point number. You can see it by my attempt of using parseFloat...

That's the only clue I had. What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: `var pes = 0(document...` results in `Uncaught TypeError: 0 is not a function`. Also, `alert` returns `undefined`, you can't call `parseFloat` on it (and what is `value`?)

Comment: Also, `addEventListener` needs another parameter; you haven’t told the computer what to do when a click happens.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Disregard the 0. I've noticed that i pasted it after cuting some lines on my vs code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistake in your code:

Did not set event handle to click event.

```
document.getElementById("btn-click").addEventListener("click", conversor);
```

Did not get value of `document.getElementById("dados").value`

`0(document` may be your typo.

```js
function conversor(){
var pes = (document.getElementById("dados").value) * 0.305;
    alert('A altura em metros é: ' + (pes));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
</head>
<html>
<title>Exercícios js</title>
    <body>
        <p>Insira os dados: </p> <input type="text" name="dados" id="dados" placeholder="Digite a altura em metros">
        <button type="button" id="btn-click" onclick="conversor()">Converter !</button>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/motor.js">
            document.getElementById("btn-click").addEventListener("click", conversor);            

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That does the work ! Thank you so much. Oddly, the very  same corrections did not work on my vs code. It returns me what i wanted: a number. But it's 0. But i've tested it here and voiíla !!